# efficient way to display subset of Doctrine collection in twig

Tags: performance, symfony, doctrine

I've got a Symfony entity, which has a `OneToMany` mapping with an `OrderBy` clause like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\News", mappedBy="category", orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "DESC"})
 */
private $news;
```

Assuming I would like to only display `n` entries in Twig, I would have the options to either loop over it and ignoring every thing after `loop.index` n or rather use [slice](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html). However these options do have the downside, that if there are a lot of news entries, all of them will be loaded, which isn't very efficient.

Another option would be to use a Criteria in the controller or the entity to limit the amount of loaded entities. If I understood it [here](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/criteria-collection-filtering) correctly, it should modify the doctrine query directly and thus not have any performance impact. Is this the best practice, or would it be better to have a custom query builder in the controller or a function in the repository?

Comment: If I understand correct you talk about lazy loading there are some options to stop it: first in mapping -> eager=FETCH; second with custom query to join only that you need; third way is to use $qb->getQuery()->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true). 
These options comes on my mind now, hopes to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can set `$news` relationship as `EXTRA_LAZY` and use `$news->slice()` function without triggering a full load as stated in [official documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html):

> If you mark an association as extra lazy the following methods on
>   collections can be called without triggering a full load of the
>   collection:
>
> ```
> Collection#contains($entity)
> Collection#containsKey($key) (available with Doctrine 2.5)
> Collection#count()
> Collection#get($key) (available with Doctrine 2.4)
> Collection#slice($offset, $length = null)
> ```

Therefore your declaration should look like the following:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\News", mappedBy="category", orphanRemoval=true, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "DESC"})
 */
private $news;
```

Comment: Very nice, just what I was looking for!